# S is a system of representatives left cosets -> S^-1 system of representatives right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let G be a group and let H is a subgroup of G. Prove the following:

**If S is a system of representatives for the left cosets of H in G, then $S^{-1}=\{s^{-1}:s \in S\}$ is a system of representatives for the right cosets of H in G**

How I tried to prove it:

s belongs to S -> $s=a*h_{1}$ for some $h_{1}$ belongs to H and for an unique a belongs to G. 
$s=a*h_{1} -> h_{1}^{-1}*a^{-1}=s^{-1}$

a is unique -> a^-1 is unique, total amount of different a^-1=total amount of different a's=$[G:H]$(=number of left and right cosets). Thus proven that each s^-1 belongs to an unique right coset of G (since $h^{-1}_{1}\in H$ and $a^{-1} \in G$)

Is my proof ok? And if not, what can I improve about it? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding any of the mathematical content, usually we write proofs in $\LaTeX$ (or mathtype, in this case) and do not overuse mathematical symbols like $\forall$, $\exists$, $\Rightarrow$. This means that we write in full sentences and try to explain what we're doing with words. In your case, although the first part of your proof is logically correct, it is hard to digest for a reader. You could improve it by cleaning up some of the parts:

> If $s \in S$, then we may write $s = ah_1$ for some $h_1 \in H$ and an unique $a \in G$. Taking the inverse of this equation gives us $h_1^{-1}a^{-1} = s^{-1}$.

And this applies to your entire proof.

In the next part, though, your logic is not clear. The number of unique $a$'s is not equal to $[G:H]$. If $s = ah_1$, then $sh_1^{-1} = a$. So $a$ is uniquely determined by our choice of $h_1 \in H$, and therefore we actually have $|H|$ choices for $a$. At this point, your proof breaks down.

**Hint?** To prove this, I would prove that $gH \mapsto Hg^{-1}$ is a well-defined bijection between between the left and right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: But by saying that, you would say that there are |H| different left cosets in G, per defintion the amount of elements in #S=|H|. But we also know per defintion that the system of representatives contains exactly one element from each left coset of G, so #S=[G:H]. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The number of choices for $a$ does not coincide with the number of cosets. My argument above shows this. I am not saying that there are $|H|$ different cosets of $G$. I am saying that there are $|H|$ different choices for $a$, and this is unrelated to the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Well, do you agree when I say that when we let a belong to the integers, the amount of aH that is contained in G is [G:H]?

Comment: The number of $aH$ in $G$ is not equal to the number of distinct values of $a$, *under the restriction that $s = ah_1$.* (And to be clear, if there are no restrictions, then the number of distinct choices of $a$ would just be $|G|$.)

Comment: Really? Do you have a counter-example for that? Because by thm for every left coset aH and bH we have aH=bH v aH intersect bH is empty, so logically speaking it would be reasonable to think that for all the different left-cosets aH in G for some a belongs to G all the different values in total of a would be equal to [G:H] or am I missing some sort of definition of something?

Comment: You're talking about different things. Sure, there are $[G:H]$ different cosets of $H$ in $G$ and every coset is of the form $aH$ for some $a \in G$. Notice how there is no restriction on $a$. We're just saying *any* $a \in G$. The point is that once we add a restriction, like $s = ah_1$, the situation is different.

Comment: To make an example: Suppose $G = \mathbb Z$ and $H = 2\mathbb Z$. Following your argument, let $s = 1$ be the representative of $1\mathbb Z$. Then $1 = a + h_1$ for some $h_1 \in 2 \mathbb Z$ and an unique value of $a$. How many possible values of $a$ are there? Well, there's clearly more than than $[G:H] = 2$. Just take $h_1 = 0, 2, 4$. Then $a$ is (uniquely) $1, -1, -3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106548/discussion-between-twstud-and-cxx).